# I cannot print value of converted string

Tags: java

I want to reverse a string. I know there are some other methods to do it but I wanted to do in a different way. There is no error but no output when I run my code. I dont understand why "String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)" doesnt return a value? Am I missing something?

```
String word = "myword";
for (int i = word.length(); i <= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)));
}
```

Comment: your loop runs while i is equal to or smaller than 0. that is never the case. Change it to: i > 0 and try again

Comment: @Stultuske The next thing OP's gonna get is an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: `for(int i = word.length()-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)`

Comment: no need for `String.valueOf()`

Comment: @Sweeper indeed. I didn't want to spoonfeed it all. I assumed that if the OP knew the first change to make, the two others would be very easily spotted on his/her own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for providing another slightly different solution:

You can use a `StringBuilder` to reverse a `String` using its method `reverse()`.
If you have a `String`, you can use it to initialize the `StringBuilder` with it and directly reverse it.
This example additionally uses an enhanced `for`-loop, which always goes through all of the elements. Using that, you can get rid of checking the length of a `String` and you won't have to use an `int i` for iterating.
**For your requirements**, this is a suitable option because you want to reverse the whole `String`.

```
String word = "myword";

for (char c : new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString().toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Note that you can use the `reverse()` method for printing the reversed word **in one line** just doing

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The first value of `i` is out of index. And I also fixed your code. Check below:

```
      String word = "myword";
      for(int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
      System.out.print(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 issues.

1. i should be initialized with word.length()-1. Other wise you will get StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
2. for loop condition should be >= 0.
   Below is the corrected code.

```
String word = "myword";
     for(int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
         System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
     }
```